# Birational Morphism to $\mathbb{P}^1$

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $E$ be a curve (so a $1$-dimensional, proper k-scheme) which is irreducible.

Let be $f:E \to \mathbb{P}^1$ be a birational morphism.

Why it is then an isomorphism?

Does it something to do with the fact that $\mathbb{P}^1$ is normal?

My thoughts:

Since $E$ is proper the morphism is closed. Futhermore, by birationality, is must be surjective. From here I surrender. Especially how to show this isomorphism on level of stalks.

I guess that using nomality of  $\mathbb{P}^1$ (therefore normality of stalks as local rings) it suffies to show that stalk maps $\mathcal{O}_{{\mathbb{P}^1},f(a)} \to \mathcal{O}_{E,a}$ are integral, but how.

Comment: If $f:X\to Y$ is a morphism of proper irreducible curves which is dominant, then it is finite. Use this to get an appropriate integrality (not the one you seek, which apriori can be false).

Comment: Thank you for the hint. Obviously a finite morphism (of schemes) implies that locally the ring morphisms are finite are therefore integral and by normality of $P^1$ the claim follows.  But I'm not sure if I understand your first argument correctly: By dominance $f$ is iso and especially finite on dense sets of both spaces. How properness imply that $f$ is finite everywhere? (I'm using wiki's definition of finite morphism)

Comment: A proper morphism which is quasi-finite (fibers are finite) is finite-not so trivial a theorem and can not be explained in brief. I suggest you read the proof in a text book.